# Getting Information from Console.log and displaying it in div

Tags: css, json, html, each

Currently I am stuck I want to return the title, plot and poster using themoviedb api I have no idea how to start the coding for this

Currently when i run a search the information is display in the console log of the browser i want to take that information and style it into a table format nothing fancy just the title and poster need help no clue where to start

doc site here http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#get-%2F3%2Fsearch%2Fmovie

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Seach</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
    mode = 'search/movie',
    input,
    movieName,
    key = '?api_key=My API KEY HERE';

    $('button').click(function() {
        var input = $('#movie').val(),
            movieName = encodeURI(input);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + mode + key + '&query='+movieName ,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="movie" type="text" /><button>Search</button>
</body>
</html>
```

output looks like this it returns objects under a movie title in his chase 300
[image]

error when running each staement

[image]

Comment: whats the output of data in console? paste that as well in your question.

Comment: For clarity, you don't want to take information from the console.log, you want to use it instead of outputting to the console.

Comment: add data from console and @Askanison4 can u show me how i get the information to the html without going threw console ??

Comment: For future reference, the Console is typically a debugging tool and not something used for production features. Use it to display information to yourself while working on your code but try not to use it in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: url + mode + key + '&query='+movieName ,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        var table = '<table>';
        $.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
          table += '<tr><td>' + value.original_title + '</td><td>' + value.release_date + '</td></tr>';
        });
            table += '</table>';
        $('.myelement').html(table);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tryed it this way but nothing showed up i have added the erro i got to the above post one other this what is $('.myelement').html(table); for

Comment: Change `$.each( data.result, function( key, value ) {` to `$.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {`

Comment: You should add an element for result. For example, `<div class="myelement"></div>`

Comment: Working now dude thank u so much one other thing can u tell me where u got the varibables like original_title just so i get them right ?

Comment: @Jamiex304 look at the console.log() image you posted. That shows the structure of the variables inside your results object

Comment: kwl thanks dude one last question i tryed posting the poster but all it gave me was the address to the poster any idea how i get that to show up ????

Comment: i have looked at that i dont a clue what i have to input ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't read from the console. It's just for outputting debug information. The AJAX call basically returns an JavaScript object (whose structure you can see in the the console).

Access the data from it just like from any other JavaScript object (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects if you need to learn how) and work with that.

EDIT: If you need to know how to display the data on the web page, you need to learn about the DOM. See for example: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-dom-intro/

Comment: i forgot to stae this i am very new to this concept can u help me write the javascript object so i can get the information ?

Comment: You allread have the object (it's the `data` variable). How ever you probably have bitten off more than you can chew, if you don't even know the basics of JavaScript. Work though a tutorial like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide before used trying advanced things like this.